# Replacing column values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame which has three columns as shown below. There are about 10,000 entries in the data frame and there are duplicates as well.

```
Hospital_ID   District_ID  Employee
Hospital 1    District 19   5 
Hospital 1    District 19   10
Hospital 1    District 19   6
Hospital 2    District 10   50
Hospital 2    District 10   51
```

Now I want to remove the duplicates but I want to replace the values in my original data frame by their mean so that it should look like this:

```
Hospital 1    District 19   7.0000
Hospital 2    District 10   50.5000
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [Emre](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/users/381/emre) already mentioned, you may use the [groupby](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) function. After that, you should apply [reset_index](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) to move the MultiIndex to the columns:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame( [ ['Hospital 1', 'District 19', 5],
                     ['Hospital 1', 'District 19', 10],
                     ['Hospital 1', 'District 19', 6],
                     ['Hospital 2', 'District 10', 50],
                     ['Hospital 2', 'District 10', 51]], columns = ['Hospital_ID', 'District_ID', 'Employee'] )

df = df.groupby( ['Hospital_ID', 'District_ID'] ).mean()
```

which gives you:

```
  Hospital_ID  District_ID  Employee
0  Hospital 1  District 19       7.0
1  Hospital 2  District 10      50.5
```

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is called [aggregation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aggregate_function); deduplication or duplicate removal is something else.  I think the code self-explanatory:

`df.groupby(['Hospital_ID', 'District_ID']).mean()`

Comment: But this will not replace the values in original dataframe and I want to replace the original values by the mean values in the original dataframe

Comment: @Nain 
`df = df.groupby(['Hospital_ID', 'District_ID']).mean()`

Comment: Rohan's method is the only way; you can not aggregate in place.